# why static block Cannot execute in sequence but jump into the other method in java?

Tags: java, static

We used a special database，so i want to write a database connection Pool,there is something wrong with the code, when i debug into the static block,at first JVM worked in the `Properties properties = new Properties();` but  next step is `int i = 0;` i dont know why it ingored the other code in the static block

public class GoldDataSource {

```
private static String goldip;
private static int goldport;
private static String username;
private static String password;
private static int maxPollSize;
private static LinkedList<Server> list = new LinkedList<Server>();

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GoldDataSource.class);

static {
    try {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        InputStream is = GoldDataSource.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/conf/db/gold.properties");
        properties.load(is);
        goldip = properties.getProperty("gold.ip");
        goldport = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("gold.port"));
        username = properties.getProperty("gold.username");
        password = properties.getProperty("gold.password");
        maxPollSize = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("gold.pool.maxPollSize"));
        for (int i = 0; i < maxPollSize; i++) {
            Server server = new ServerImpl(goldip, goldport, username, password);
            server.connect();
            server.login();
            list.add(server);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ....
    }
}


public synchronized static Server getServer() {
    try {
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            Server aServer = list.removeFirst();
            if (aServer != null) {
                return aServer;
            } else {
                if (i >= 3) {

                    return aServer;
                }
                Thread.sleep(500);
                i++;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
        return null;
    }
}

public static void closeServer(Server aServer) {
    list.addLast(aServer);
}}
```

I used `Server server = GoldDataSource.getServer();` to get connection,but when it executed `Properties properties = new Properties();`then jump into the code `int i = 0;` which in the `getServer()` method

---

I edited the code with singleton pattern，it worked ,but i still do not understand why the old code didn't worked , and i catched "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" in the first catch block old code.

public class GoldDataSource {

```
private static String goldip;
private static int goldport;
private static String username;
private static String password;
private static int maxPollSize;
private static LinkedList<Server> list = new LinkedList<Server>();
private static InputStream is;

private static GoldDataSource aDataSource = new GoldDataSource();

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GoldDataSource.class);


private goldDataSource() {
    try {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        is = GoldDataSource.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/conf/db/gold.properties");
        properties.load(is);
        goldip = properties.getProperty("gold.ip");
        goldport = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("gold.port"));
        username = properties.getProperty("gold.username");
        password = properties.getProperty("gold.password");
        maxPollSize = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("gold.pool.maxPollSize"));
        for (int i = 0; i < maxPollSize; i++) {
            Server server = new ServerImpl(goldip, goldport, username, password);
            server.connect();
            server.login();
            list.add(server);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static goldDataSource getDateSource() {
    return aDataSource;
}


public synchronized Server getServer() {
    try {
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            Server aServer = list.removeFirst();
            if (aServer != null) {
                return aServer;
            } else {
                if (i >= 3) {
                    return aServer;
                }
                Thread.sleep(500);
                i++;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("get connection error：" + e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}

public void closeServer(Server aServer) {
    list.addLast(aServer);
}
```

}

Comment: Where is `Server server = GoldDataSource.getServer();` line in the code?

Comment: Perhaps `getResourceAsStream` fails?

Comment: Are you talking about breakpoints in your IDE?

Comment: 1) Remember to close the `InputStream`. 2) You should not do all that in a `static` block. Instead, you should implement this using the singleton pattern, e.g. see [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/70689/5221149)

Comment: @Steve Smith yes in the IDE

Comment: For future posts, please take the time to read your own question, and fix any mistakes you may find. It is hard to help if one also has to deal with broken language, typos, wrong formatting, etc.

Comment: What is in your `catch` block in your static initializer? It seems most likely that the intializer is failing and you are swallowing the exception.

Comment: @DaveH just print the log

Comment: @C-Otto THX，sorry about that,i am not good at "markdown" skill

Comment: @Andreas yes i forgot about it,but i dont konw why it didn't worked

Comment: @pingandpong the formatting is easy to fix, but typos and confusing sentences are not.

Comment: @C-Otto thanks for your advice, my mother language is not english but i will pay more attention on it

Comment: So does anything get printed by your catch block?

Comment: @DaveH no,I'm at home now. I can't connect to the database. I'll try again tomorrow

Comment: Static _initializer_ blocks are to initialize a class. Yours does way too much for logic that executes before a class is initialized. Get rid of all the crap from the initializer that has nothing to do with class initialization, and likely shouldn't even be static in the first place. You're begging for bugs the way you're doing it. And remember, it's "static _initializer_ block", for a reason.

Comment: @LewBlochI know that this writing may not appropriate, I loaded the properties in the static block, but I still do not understand the problem, I hope to know why.